# Why Doesn't Robomongo See The "test" Database?

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I've set up a local version of MongoDB and installed Robomongo, but currently Robomongo only shows two databases under localhost: "admin" and "local". However in the Mongo shell when I type the "db" command, the value "test" gets spat out. This makes sense because supposedly the default database is "test".

That-said though, how come Robomongo doesn't see the "test" database? Is it because it's empty? The "admin" database also has 0 collections, 0 functions, and 0 users so I'd assume that means it's empty as well, no?

Comment: Likely because `admin` is a special database. Try adding data to a collection in `test`.

Comment: @wdberkeley -- If you put that in an answer I'd be happy to give you credit by marking accepted because I just tried out your solution and indeed you are correct.